# What would be the best way to do http url polling using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I need to have my Spring application poll a given URL every `X` minutes and then publish an application event based on the HTTP status code returned by the remote server. I'm interested in some specific status codes: 200 (then handle the content), 404 (then raise error message) and 301 (then do nothing.)

I do not want to reinvent the wheel, so...

What would be the best way to achieve this ? Is there anything available out of the box (for instance in spring-integration, but any other library is welcome) or do I have to write it myself ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration is the best choice for this.
Here's a sample integration route:

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel" expression="''">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="60000"></int:poller>
 </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="quakeinfo.channel">
    <int:queue capacity="10"/>
</int:channel>


<int:channel id="quakeinfotrigger.channel"></int:channel>   

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="quakerHttpGateway"
    request-channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel"
    url="http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojson/all/hour"
    http-method="GET"
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
    charset="UTF-8"
    reply-timeout="5000"
    reply-channel="quakeinfo.channel">      
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Gist of the full source : Refer : [Link](https://gist.github.com/bijukunjummen/4083151#file-httpgateway-xml)